# pLepage function in R

Tags: r, debugging

Here is a self-define function for computing Lepage D statistic, which returns result different from the D statistic generated by `NSM3::pLepage()`:

```
LepageD <- function(x, y){
  m=length(x); n=length(y); N=m+n
  z=sort(c(x,y),index=TRUE)
  rz=seq(1,(N-1)/2); rz=c(rz,(N+1)/2,rev(rz))
  r=rz[sort(z$ix,index=TRUE)$ix]
  C=sum(r[12:21])
  rk=rank(c(x,y))
  W=sum(rk[12:21])
  Wstar=(W-n*(N+1)/2)/sqrt(m*n*(N+1)/12)
  Cstar=(C-n*((N+1)^2)/(4*N))/sqrt(m*n*(N+1)*(3+N^2)/(48*(N^2)))
  D=Wstar^2+Cstar^2
  D
}

> LepageD(1:10, 2:12)
[1] 1.09216
> pLepage(1:10, 2:12)$obs.stat
[1] 1.112263
```

And my function is not able to deal with situation `x` and `y` have same sample size.

```
> LepageD(1:10, 2:11)
[1] NA
```

I'm confused about where I did wrong.

Answer (score 0):

According to me, the problem lies somewhere around this line:

```
r=rz[sort(z$ix,index=TRUE)$ix]
```

The reason for error occurence here is that z (in the test case giving output as NA) has 20 elements.

So, sort(z$ix,index=TRUE)$ix produces output as:

```
1  2  4  6  8 10 12 14 16 18  3  5  7  9 11 13 15 17 19 20
```

Also, the length of vector rz is 19 (and not 20).

Content of rz vector:

```
 [1]  1.0  2.0  3.0  4.0  5.0  6.0  7.0  8.0  9.0 10.5  9.0  8.0  7.0  6.0  5.0
[16]  4.0  3.0  2.0  1.0
```

So, when we try to access the 20th element of vector rz, it produces NA.

As you haven't used the na.rm = T argument while doing the sum, the values for C and W becomes NA.

And which results Wstar, Cstar and ultimately D to become NA.